# How to get serviceManager to work on a class zf2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, laminas-api-tools

I have some services defined on my module.php that works as intended declared as:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'Marketplace\V1\Rest\Service\ServiceCollection' =>  function($sm) {
                    $tableGateway = $sm->get('ServiceCollectionGateway');
                    $table = new ServiceCollection($tableGateway);
                    return $table;
                },
            'ServiceCollectionGateway' => function ($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('PdoAdapter');
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new ServiceEntity());
                    return new TableGateway('service', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },
            'Marketplace\V1\Rest\User\UserCollection' =>  function($sm) {
                    $tableGateway = $sm->get('UserCollectionGateway');
                    $table = new UserCollection($tableGateway);
                    return $table;
                },
            'UserCollectionGateway' => function ($sm) {
                    $dbAdapter = $sm->get('PdoAdapter');
                    $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                    $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new UserEntity());
                    return new TableGateway('user', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
                },
        ),
    );
}
```

I use them to map my db tables to an object. From my main classes of my project I can access them without any problem. Take a look of my project file tree:

[image]

For example, userResource.php extends abstractResource and this function works:

```
public function fetch($id)
{
    $result = $this->getUserCollection()->findOne(['id'=>$id]);
    return $result;
}
```

Inside ResourceAbstract I have:

```
<?php

namespace Marketplace\V1\Abstracts;

use ZF\Rest\AbstractResourceListener;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class ResourceAbstract extends AbstractResourceListener implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface {

    protected $serviceLocator;


    public function getServiceCollection() {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        return $sm->get('Marketplace\V1\Rest\Service\ServiceCollection');
    }

    public function getUserCollection() {
        $sm = $this->getServiceLocator();
        return $sm->get('Marketplace\V1\Rest\User\UserCollection');
    }

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }

    public function getServiceLocator() {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }

}
```

There as suggested by the Zf2 documentation I need to implement ServiceLocatorAwareInterface in order to use the serviceManager. So far so good. Then I decided to add a new class, call Auth.

This class is not very different from abstractResource, it gets call in loginController like this:

```
<?php
namespace Marketplace\V1\Rpc\Login;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Marketplace\V1\Functions\Auth;

class LoginController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function loginAction()
    {
        $auth = new Auth();
        $data = $this->params()->fromPost();
        var_dump($auth->checkPassword($data['email'], $data['password']));

        die;
    }


}
```

This is Auth:

```
<?php

namespace Marketplace\V1\Functions;


use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorAwareInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class Auth implements ServiceLocatorAwareInterface {

    protected $serviceLocator;

    public function setServiceLocator(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }

    public function getServiceLocator() {
        return $this->serviceLocator;
    }

    public function checkPassword($email, $rawPassword) {

        $user = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Marketplace\V1\Rest\User\UserCollection')->findByEmail($email);
        if($user)
            return false;

        $result = $this->genPassword($rawPassword, $user->salt);

        if($result['password'] === $user->password)
            return true;
        else
            return false;

    }

    public function genPassword($rawPassword, $salt = null) {
        if(!$salt)
            $salt = mcrypt_create_iv(22, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);
        $options = [
            'cost' => 11,
            'salt' => $salt,
        ];
        return ['password' => password_hash($rawPassword, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, $options), 'salt' => bin2hex($salt)];
    }

}
```

As you can see it follows the same path that abtractResource do, BUT, in this case when I execute loginController I get an error:

```
Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function get() on null in C:\WT-NMP\WWW\MarketPlaceApi\module\Marketplace\src\Marketplace\V1\Functions\Auth.php on line 25
```

And that refers to this line: `$user = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Marketplace\V1\Rest\User\UserCollection')->findByEmail($email);`

Meaning that getServiceLocator is empty. Why I cant get serviceLocator to work on Auth class but I can in abstractResource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the `ServiceLocator` is injected through a mechanism called 'setter injection'. For that to happen, something (e.g., `ServiceManager`) needs to call a setter for a class, in this case `setServiceLocator`. When you directly instantiate `Auth` that's not the case. You need to add your class to the service locator, for example as an invokable service.

E.g.:

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
    return array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Auth' => '\Marketplace\V1\Functions\Auth',
        ),
    );
}
```

or, more appriopriatly as it doesn't use a anonymous function for a factory, put it in your modules config file `modules/Marketplace/config/module.config.php':

```
// ... 
'service_manager' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
        'Auth' => '\Marketplace\V1\Functions\Auth',
    ),
),
```

and the you can get `Auth` from the service locator in your controller:

```
$auth = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Auth');
```

instead of:

```
$auth = new Auth;
```

This way the service locator will construct `Auth` for you, check what interfaces it implements and when it finds out that it does implement `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` then it'll run the setter passing an instance of itself into it. Fun fact: the controller itself gets injected an instance of service locator the same way (it's an ancestor of [this class](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php) implementing the very same interface). Another fun fact: that behaviour may change in future as [discussed here](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/issues/5168).

Comment: I've expanded the answer. I think we've just build a skyscraper here.

Comment: So does that answer your question? Did it help?

Comment: For some reason I cant get it to work, im getting a Call to undefined method Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::checkPassword() in 
<b>C:\WT-NMP\WWW\MarketPlaceApi\module\Marketplace\src\Marketplace\V1\Rpc\Login\LoginController.php

CheckPassword as you can see IS a function of Auth

Comment: Weird, must have made a mistake in my answer. The line to get the service should read: `$auth = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Auth');`. `$auth = $this->getServiceLocator('Auth')` would assign the service locator, and not the service, to `$auth`. Hence the error.